# How not to pass the locale through an ssh connection command

Tags: bash, ssh

I have some aliases for ssh, example:

```
alias buildWork="ssh work '~/build_app'"
```

The problem is that the `ssh` command passes some variables like `$LC_CTYPE` that causes some errors.

How to prevent that and use the server configurations ?

Comment: I don't have a way to test, but `( unset LC_CTYPE ; ssh ..... ) ` might work. This will temporarily unset LC_CTYPE in a sub-shell (the `(...)`) and then run  your `ssh ....`command. Good luck.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

It sounds like your SSH client is configured to forward the locale settings. You can prevent this by altering your configuration (the global file is typically `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`):

```
# comment out / remove the following line
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Alternatively you can change the configuration of the server, by editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote machine (note the **d** in `sshd_config`):

```
# comment out / remove the following line
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Comment: This saved me hours! And don't forget to `reload your sshd service` after you edit the `sshd_config` on the server.

Answer (score 20):

As already explained in other answers, the client will send all environment variables specified via `SendEnv` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. You can also force `ssh` to not send already defined variable names, using your user's configuration.

From [OpenSSH man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#SendEnv):

> It is possible to clear previously set SendEnv variable names by prefixing patterns with -. The default is not to send any environment variables.

So, to prevent sending your locale, you can put the following into your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
SendEnv -LC_* -LANG*
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest answer, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I finally found this as the reason it didn't work for me. They closed the issue but they didn't really solve the problem AFAICT: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285

Comment: This is completely bonkers. Debian, and derivatives such as Ubuntu, used to set `SendEnv` in a way regular users can't prevent - only `root` can change that. Clearly a bug. [This was reported in 2010, fixed in 2018](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=573316), and the fix still hasn't reached our Ubuntu 18.04 systems as of today (they run openssh 7.6p1). So the actual fix is to upgrade to a newer Debian or Debian-based release - then this answer will work.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 20.04, I reverted to SetEnv instead.

Comment: @reinierpost: I'm afraid upgrading won't solve the problem. As the default `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` in Debian contains `SendEnv LC_* LANG*`, and it is read *after* `~/.ssh/config`, you'd be basically "unmarking" vars that were not yet marked for sending. `SetEnv` might work, but it requires you to clear all your `LC_`* and both `LANG`*, as it does not accept wildcards by definition.

Comment: Why? I use a wrapper script `lclessly` that does just that, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This **does not work**, you can't "unset" the global `SendEnv` because `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is applied *after* user config.

Answer (score 17):

In short:

```
$ touch ~/.ssh/config
$ ssh -F ~/.ssh/config your_user@your_host
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/874765/642909) for details.

Comment: That one did the trick. question is why is not taking the user configuration but the global one?

Comment: @crsuarezf is it taking the user configuration, but if you don't use `-F`, it *also* takes the global configuration, instead of ignoring it completely. From the [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh): `If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored`

Comment: I already had an `~/.ssh/config` file, so all this does is update the time on that file. And the unrecognized local variables are still passed through to the host. At least now I have something to look for in the `man` page.

Comment: @Vince the reason that this works is the -F option. It forces ssh to not use the system-wide config. This is most often the file that contains a setting like "Host \*\n. 
 SendEnv LANG LC_*"

Comment: To not type that every time you could create an alias:
`alias ssh='ssh -F ~/.ssh/config $@'`

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer is correct, but, if you don't want to change your config files, you can override specific locale on the command line

```
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" ssh user@example.com
```

In fact, other env variables can be overriden on the fly

```
date; TZ='EST' date; TZ='UTC' date
```

Result

```
Tue 14 Nov 2023 06:00:37 PM -03
Tue 14 Nov 2023 04:00:37 PM EST
Tue 14 Nov 2023 09:00:37 PM UTC
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I use `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" ssh xxx@xxxx` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue that I attributed to ssh passing the locale settings, so I tried with disabling it on client site, then on server site as well (as advised above) and still the locale was complaining after logging in.

Turned out to be a messy locale on the destination server itself, where the setting was taken from `/etc/default/locale`

I had to clean it completely, run `# dpkg-reconfigure locales` which fixed the issue.

Answer (score -6):

```
   To stop sending Environment Variables via sftp 
   Tested on CENTOS 7
 - create file config in ~/xyzuser/.ssh/config
 - set permission to 600 ~/xyzuser/.ssh/config
 - Put the following content in the file

   comment the below lines commented to disable env variables#########

 - Send locale-related environment variables
        SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY 
       SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE
       SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
       SendEnv XMODIFIERS

  Running without the ~/xyzuser/.ssh/config
   sftp -v   xyzuser@destinationhost
     -------------------truncated output--------
     debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
     debug1: Entering interactive session.
     debug1: Sending environment.
     debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
     debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp

  Running with the ~/xyzuser/.ssh/config

    sftp -v -F /home/xyzuser/.ssh/config  xyzuser@destinationhost

     ----truncated----------
     debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
     debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
     debug1: Entering interactive session.
     debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
     Connected to destinationhost
```

Comment: Please actually try to answer the question instead of copy-pasting.