# fresh minikube install hangs when starting (ssh error)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am getting the error below when issuing minikube start (minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --v=7) command:

```
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Getting to WaitForSSH function...
Using SSH client type: external
Using SSH private key: /root/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa (-rw-------)
&{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /root/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa -p 22] /usr/bin/ssh <nil>}
About to run SSH command:
exit 0
SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255:
Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : ssh command error:
command : exit 0
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

When researching the above log lines i have noticed the ssh command isn't targeting the minikube virtual machine IP but 127.0.0.1. If manually run the ssh command to 127.0.0.1 i get a permission denied error.

```
/usr/bin/ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /root/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa -p 22
Warning: Permanently added '127.0.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

shouldn't the script connect to the minikube IP other than 127.0.0.1? here is the output from vboxmanage showvminfo

```
/usr/bin/VBoxManage showvminfo minikube | grep NIC
NIC 1:           MAC: 08002790443F, Attachment: NAT, Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 1 Settings:  MTU: 0, Socket (send: 64, receive: 64), TCP Window (send:64, receive: 64)
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = ssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 37549, guest ip = , guest port = 22
NIC 2:           MAC: 08002790D54C, Attachment: Host-only Interface 'vboxnet0', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
```

My system layout is as follows:

- Vmwareplayer 6.0.5 build-2443746, hypervisor config enabled.
- Ubuntu 17.04
- virtualbox 5.1.22
- minikube version: v0.21.0
- kubectl version 1.7.0

thanks in advance

Comment: can you simply try minikube delete and minikube start commands...

Comment: I issued the "minikube delete" command and got the output below:
E0820 17:03:22.318403    3455 notify.go:54] Error getting json from minikube version url: Error getting minikube version url via http: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases.json: dial tcp: lookup storage.googleapis.com: no such host
Deleting local Kubernetes cluster...
Machine deleted.

Comment: and then when using minikube start it does not start saying that the minikube machine doesn't exist: E0820 17:04:57.907022    3578 start.go:135] Error starting host:  Error getting state for host: machine does not exist

Comment: Check the status of ~/.minikube/machines/ may be previous configurations still present. Do the clean up and try. It will work otherwise add WantUpdateNotification: false in ~/.minikube/config/config.json or else create it if it's not there.

Comment: I also deleted the vm with minikube delete and erased all inside ~/.minikube with rm -rf .I created the file ~/.minikube/config/config.json as it didn't exist before with the WantUpdateNotification option you mentioned. when i issue minikube start again i get the same error ssh error I reported. is it relevant i am running everything as root? (it is a burner machine with no relevant data in it)

Comment: check this thread it might helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885748/ssh-script-returns-255-error

Comment: thanks @mohan08p for all your efforts.I did already what that post says and used the command ssh -F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /root/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa -p 22 ... as you can see it points attempts to ssh to 127.0.0.1 with username docker and that doesn't work.

Comment: Another issue with running kubernetes on Minikube v0.21.0 is that if you restart your cluster and forget to specify version on the start -- "something" gets upgraded and localkube will no longer start (even if you stop and restart the VM with the correct kubernetes-version setting). Anyways all the best @eslimasec Hope you have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

@eslimasec, minikube ssh always use port forward to access vm:

```
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = ssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 37549, guest ip = , guest port = 22
```

when you `ssh to 127.0.0.1:37549 will forward to vm:22`

so when you test ssh toward `minikube vm`, should use `port 37549` instead of `22`,

```
/usr/bin/ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /root/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa -p **37549**
```

and this is also root cause in your minikube start.

Hope it is helpful.