# pdsh not working with ips in the file

Tags: bash, macos, shell, ssh, command-line

I have a text file, like this:

```
cat hed.txt
10.21.23.12
10.23.12.12
```

I can ssh to each ip without without prompting for the key verification.

I want to run a command on each of these IPs, so I was using [pdsh](http://macappstore.org/pdsh/). I tried multiple options, but I am getting following error:

```
pdsh -w  ^hed uptime
00f12e86-cfcc-4239-9dfc-006b65a319c3: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 00f12e86-cfcc-4239-9dfc-006b65a319c3: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
pdsh@saurabh: 00f12e86-cfcc-4239-9dfc-006b65a319c3: ssh exited with exit code 255
```

I mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/803681/554084), I tried following as well, but this also gave same error.

```
PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" pdsh  -R ssh -w  ^hed  uptime
```

Also tried comment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689061/1610034), but no help.

```
PDSH_SSH_ARGS_APPEND="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" pdsh  -R ssh   ^hed  uptime
pdsh@saurabh: no remote hosts specified
```

I am able to do csshx on these via: `csshX --host hed.txt`, which works but `pdsh` will suit more for my work which is not working.

Comment: Maybe try setting the env variable `export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh` ...

Comment: @l'L'l This also gives `ssh exited with exit code 255`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, This worked like this:

```
pdsh -w  '^hed.txt' uptime
```

For my colleagues it is working without quotes as well with same version of pdsh, which is weird.