# `docker-machine ls` command showing different outputs depending on which shell I use?

Tags: bash, powershell, docker, cmd

I'm getting different results for `docker-machine ls` depending on which shell I'm using in Windows - it only seems to work in the Docker Quickstart Terminal (I'm using Docker Toolbox). I've added in the response for `docker-machine env` for more details.

Docker QS Terminal:
[image]

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.09.0

$ docker-machine env
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="D:\Developer\Docker\machine\machines\default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)
```

Powershell (same result in cmd):
[image]

```
PS > docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running                 Unknown   ssh command error:
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :

PS > docker-machine env
Error checking TLS connection: ssh command error:
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

Git Bash:
[image]

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default            virtualbox   Timeout

$ docker-machine env
Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running
```

So, my questions are, why is it only working in Docker Quickstart Terminal? Why the SSH command error in Powershell/cmd? And why the timeout in Git Bash?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14885748/1630171).